# How to define an extern function in multiple files and specify which definition to use?

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

Not sure if `extern` is the correct way to handle this situation, but it is what I've currently attempted.

I have a library sharing common code across multiple projects, some of which have different pin configuration that must be done during the `_system_pre_init()` function in the library (which is called prior to `main()` due to microprocessor behavior).

Ex:

**boot.cpp**

```
extern void Init(void);

// called prior to main() due to microprocessor behavior
extern "C" int _system_pre_init(void)
{
    Init();

    return 1;
}
```

**board1.hpp**

```
void Init(void);
```

**board1.cpp**

```
void Init(void)
{
    // init specific to board 1
}
```

**board2.hpp**

```
void Init(void);
```

**board2.cpp**

```
void Init(void)
{
    // init specific to board 2
}
```

The plan was for the project implementing the libary to #include whatever board header it needed, which would in turn define the appropriate Init() function.

**main.cpp**

```
#include "board1.hpp"

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    //...
}
```

However, it doesn't look like the board header I include has any effect over the definition of Init().  How can I manage this?  Or is there some other paradigm that fits better here?

Comment: it looks like the function `_system_pre_init(void)` is in one file and the `main()` is in another.  Are both files compiled at the same time allowing the board type to be specified at compile time or does the function `_system_pre_init(void)` need to make the initialization decision at run time?  When is `_system_pre_init(void)` actually invoked versus when is `main()` invoked?  Does `main()` actually need to know what board is being used or could it ask `_system_pre_init(void)`?

Comment: Have you considered creating separate libraries for board1, board2, boardN, and using the only one that is appropriate for a project?

Comment: Main (or often the startup code of a bsp 'board support package') must query something on the hardware (call it inventory?) to discover on which board the code is running.  OSE and vxWorks both provide BSP's designed to make this easy.  Are you rolling your own?  No matter.  This is a typical chicken-and-egg challenge to getting a code running on 'either' target.  Most code designed to run on more than one configuration must discover something unique about that card.  Usually a rom 'inventory', but possibly 1 card has an interface the other does not.

Comment: @RichardChambers correct, different files.  They are compiled at the same time.  `_system_pre_init` is invoked prior to `main`.  `_system_pre_init` doesn't know what board is being used, which is really the root of the problem.

Comment: @RSahu Unfortunately, separate libaries for each board is not an ideal solution for my situation.

Comment: @DOUGLASO.MOEN Providing the board headers is an attempt to provide a "compile-time definition" of board hardware instead of a "runtime discovery".  I'm hoping this is in someway possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Providing the board headers is an attempt to provide a "compile-time
>   definition" of board hardware instead of a "runtime discovery". I'm
>   hoping this is in someway possible

At most of my embedded system employment this idea was implemented in the make file.  i.e. you either build target1  or you build target2.  The decision of which you are building is done by the user by selecting the correct target of the make file.

When building the whole system, you would specify 'all'.

With the target identified, the make file only builds the files required by that target.

Conditional compilation flags were not used.

But, perhaps this is not useful ... if you don't use make.

Comment: Actually this is a good alternative to using conditional compilation whether using `make` or using an IDE.  Most IDEs have some kind of a `make` facility which the IDE uses to execute the build command to minimize the amount of compilation done  So it would be a matter of setting up various targets in the IDE with each configuration using a different version of the board.cpp file to fit the specific target board. In Visual Studio there is the Configuration Manager for instance which typically has two configurations, Debug and Release but there is nothing stopping you from adding others.

Comment: I'm using CMake, so this solution ended up working perfectly.  The project implementing the common library specifies what board file source to include in its CMakeLists.txt.  Allows the flexibility to keep common board files in the library and also allow for specific board files outside of the library to be used.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It appears that what you are wanting to do is to have a decision at compile time as to what board the application will be using. The function `_system_pre_init(void)` needs to know which board.

The approach I would consider would be to have a compiler command line define as part of your build environment which would select the target board type. This compiler command line define would then be used in file boot.cpp to include either board1.cpp or board2.cpp, or what ever.  Notice that I am saying the board definition C++ source files and not the header files.

The different versions of the boards would all have the same function names, classes, etc. though the implementation would be board specific.

Since the board implementation file would be included into the boot.cpp file it would mean that what ever board file that is included, as determined by the compiler command line option, would be available for the function `_system_pre_init(void)` as well as the rest of your code.

So for instance you may have a compiler command line option of `-DBOARDTYPE=1` or `-DBOARDTYPE=2` and then in your boot.cpp file you would have preprocessor macros such as:

```
#if BOARDTYPE == 1
#include "board1.cpp"
#elif BOARDTYPE == 2
#include "board2.cpp"
#endif

// called prior to main() due to microprocessor behavior
extern "C" int _system_pre_init(void)
{
    Init();

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Good solution, thanks.  Ended up going with the make approach because it lets boot.cpp be board file agnostic, but otherwise this would have worked well

Answer (score 0):

I can see two options:

1. Macro - in each header (`board1.hpp`, `board2.hpp`) define a macro like this

`#define Init Init_boardN`

where `Init_boardN` would be your specific function to init board number `N`.
This allows you to call `Init` in the old way as `Init()`.

2. Additional argument to the `Init` function (suggested enum) to tell it which board to init. You can call the real init function (specific to board) from body of `Init` based on the argument.

Comment: Not sure I follow...if I `#define Init Init_boardN`, then the call to Init() in boot.cpp will be undefined, correct?